# how to make managed->unmanaged call where a string is copied to a parameter?

Tags: c#, unmanaged, native-code

I have in unmanaged dll:

```
char *DuplicateForCLR(const char *pString)
{
    char *pRetVal;
    auto Length = MyStrlen(pString);

    pRetVal = (char*)CoTaskMemAlloc((Length + 1) * sizeof(char));

    MyStrcpy(pRetVal, pString);

    return pRetVal;
}
extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport) int InitConfigAndEnvironment(int argc, char *argv[], char **ppReadFile)
{
   auto ret = ConfigInit(argc, argv);
   if (ret != 0)
   {
       *ppReadFile = DuplicateForCLR(ConfigGetReadFile());
       ret = 1;
   }
   return ret;
}
```

and in managed:

```
[DllImport(DllName, CallingConvention = DllCallingConvention)]
public static extern int InitConfigAndEnvironment(int argc, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string[] argv, out string readConfigFile);
```

However after adding this call I started to get weird problems (probably corrupted memory) and I don't know if this is 100% correct way to do this.

Comment: Is the return pRetVal inside the function?

Comment: "weird problems" - maybe you can elucidate a bit?

Comment: @Rob, yes. I fixed it. "weird problems" is for example that I got different kind of exceptions from same code when I tried to load resource dictionary. The point is that my code works, but does it corrupt the memory while it seems to work. E.g: Is char ** same as out string?

Comment: Looks okay, but native code rarely needs help from pinvoke to corrupt memory.  That ConfigGetReadFile() looks pretty ugly from a distance, hard to see how it isn't going to leak memory for example.  Write unit tests to gain confidence that the native code isn't borken.